# How to create each directory tar in a directory and save to different localtion

Tags: bash, backup, tar

I have multiple directory in /home/ path and i want to make script to make `.tar` for each folder and save into another location.

After googling what i have found is:

```
find /home/ -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec tar cvf {}.tar {}  \;
```

but my **problem** is this is creating `.tar` files in `/home` and after that i have to move them to another location which is taking long time.

what i **want** is, `tar` file should be create in another location not in `/home/` directory.

Thanks:
 Akash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple **script** worked for me.

```
#!/bin/bash
DW=`date +%a`
DM=`date +%d`

cd /home/
for file in *;
do
tar -czvf /databackup_Allin/$DW/home/$file.tar.gz $file;
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The last argument is the tar command. The `{}` are replaced by the name found by the `find` command. For example if the `find` command is about to work with `foo/` directory then `{}` will be replaced with `foo/`. This will allow you to designate the location.

```
SEARCH_DIR=/home
OUTPUT_DIR=/tmp
cd "$SEARCH_DIR" && find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec tar cvf "$OUTPUT_DIR/{}.tar" {} \;
```

To break this down further:

- `cd "$SEARCH_DIR"` - change the current directory to the `OUTPUT_DIR` (in this case `/home`)<sup>1</sup>
- `&&` After changing directory do the following...
- `find .` - search for things in the current directory<sup>1</sup>
- `-maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1` - don't recursively dive deeper than one level (top level, same as doing an `ls`)
- `-type d` - only output directories (ignore files)
- `-exec` - run the following command on each entity that `find` comes across based on the previous filter options
- `tar cvf /tmp/{}.tar {}` - execute the tar command to create (verbosely) the file `/tmp/{}.tar` (where `{}` is replaced with the entity `find` is has currently found) and only include the contents of `{}` (the directly /entity that `find` found
- `\;` - Tell `find` this is the end of the `-exec` command

In summary this command will tar each directory in `$SEARCH_DIR` to a file in `$OUTPUT_DIR` named appropriately.

---

1. The current directory is important because the output from `find` prefixes the first argument to its output. If you did not change directory and instead passed the directory to `find` itself the output would look significanly different:

   ```
   $ find .
   foo
   bar
   $ find /home
   /home/foo
   /home/bar
   ```

   In this case we want the former so that the `tar` command executes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried specifying the directory like this?

`find /home/ -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec tar cvf \path\to\directory\{}.tar {} \;`

Comment: I tried your suggestion but getting below error:


`tar: /databackup_Allin/Tue/home//home/akash.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now`